# Why do I have to push my string into an array only to join it back again?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, join, capitalize

So I want to capitalize the starting letter of each word in a string. Here's how I did it:

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
var arr = str.split(" ");
var newArr = [];
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var newStr = arr[i].toString();
    newArr.push(newStr.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + newStr.substring(1,newStr.length));
  }
  return newArr.join(" ");

}
```

This code is correct and the first letter of every word in the string was capitalized. However, when I tried to shorten my code like this, it only returned the last word of the string with the first letter capitalized, but nothing else:

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
var arr = str.split(" ");
var newArr = [];
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var newStr = arr[i].toString();
  }
  return newStr.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + newStr.substring(1,newStr.length);

}
```

Basically, what I did was remove the part where I push the new string into a new array, only to join it back into a string.

Comment: Read the two code snippets again. Follow their actions through. How do they differ? Hint: In the latter case the line with `return` is only called *once* for the entire string (with the last value of newStr assigned); while in the former case the capitalization is done for *each* of the individual words, as split, and then all the separate capitalized results are joined again.

Comment: That because you always create a new variable `newStr`inside the loop and it takes the last one to be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in the `for` loop part code. Here in every iteration the `newstr` get the value of `arr[i].toString();` and the old value i.e `arr[i-1].toString();` which is in `newStr` is overwritten. Hence only the last iteration value is stored in `newStr`

```
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 var newStr = arr[i].toString();
}
```

Try this:

```js
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
 var arr = str.split(" ");
 var newStr = "";  
 for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var temp = arr[i].toString();
    newStr =  newStr + temp.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + temp.substring(1,temp.length)+" ";
   }
 return newStr;
}

alert(LetterCapitalize("hello i am rohit "));
```

Comment: Test your code; it does not works (Reference error. But too the algo si wrong)

Comment: Updated, some minor mistakes as I didn't tested. Thanks chumklu !! This one is correct see the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you got confused by the return in the [MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functionality:

```js
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
  var arr = str.split(" "),
   newArr = arr.map(
     function(word) { 
       return word.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
     });
  return newArr.join(" ");
}

alert(LetterCapitalize("This is a test"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You may achieve this through replace function without splitting.

```
function LetterCapitalize(str) { 
  return str.replace(/(^| )([a-z])/g, function(x,y,z) {
    return y+z.toUpperCase()
  }
    )
}
console.log(LetterCapitalize('foo bar buz'))
```